# Powershell & bcdedit: Identify recovery partitions

Tags: powershell, recovery, disaster-recovery, bcdedit, bcdstore

I am trying to script the elimination/backup of the OEM partition (which just brings back the system to an outdated version of no practical use).

On many systems, using DISKPART `list partition` returns more `recovery` type partitions: one is the official Microsoft Recovery Tools partition (WinRE) and others come from the OEMs.

The first step is to safely identify the position of the WinRE partition. I did not find any straight way in `bcdedit` or PS other than:

```
$renv=(bcdedit /enum "{default}" | Select-String "^recoverysequence" | Out-String | Select-String "{.+}").Matches.Value
(bcdedit /enum $renv | Select-String "^device" | Out-String | Select-String "\[.+\]").Matches.Value
```

This returns a string like:

```
[\Device\HarddiskVolume1]
```

where the volume number is the partition to use in `Diskpart`. (Remaining recovery partitions and the OEM type partitions can be backupped).

Is this the correct procedure to identify the WinRE partition?

Any more straight and/or better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a command line tool called ReagentC, and it's in the path, so you can call it from any administrative command prompt.

```
reagentc /info
```

...will produce some output like:

```
Windows RE status:         Enabled
Windows RE location:       \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition4\Recovery\WindowsRE
Boot Configuration Data (BCD) identifier: 496c58c4-71cb-11e9-af8f-001c42903d2e
Recovery image location:   
Recovery image index:      0
Custom image location:     
Custom image index:        0
```

Also, if you're writing code to do the work, you can discover the recovery partition by calling a winapi function to do the work. It's an obnoxiously complicated api to call...but for what it's worth, it's `DeviceIOControl` with the control code of `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX`. If you're not using C or some language that defines unions, this is a pain. The structure you get back varies with whether the disk is GPT or MBR format.

If the disk is MBR, the returned partition type will be 0x27, and if it's a GPT drive the partition type will be the guid: `de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac`.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from streamlining the Select-String with a [Lookbehind-RE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
I dont't see a better approach ATM.

```
$renv=(bcdedit /enum "{default}" | Select-String "(?<=^recoverysequence\s+)({.+})").Matches.Value
(bcdedit /enum $renv | Select-String "(?<=^device.+)\[.+\]").Matches.Value
[\Device\HarddiskVolume5]
```